# How to get image from https://exampe.com/captcha.ashx

Tags: c#, html, httpclient

I'm trying to get a recaptcha image from an external site, but I always receive an html response instead.

The returned html is:

```
<html> 
<head>
<title>TuEnvio</title>
  <style> body { background-color: #dfe6e9; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); transform: translate(-50%, -50%); } .lds-grid { display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 80px; height: 80px; } .lds-grid div { position: absolute; width: 16px; height: 16px; border-radius: 50%; background: #d63031; animation: lds-grid 1.2s linear infinite; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(1) { top: 8px; left: 8px; animation-delay: 0s; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(2) { top: 8px; left: 32px; animation-delay: -0.4s; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(3) { top: 8px; left: 56px; animation-delay: -0.8s; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(4) { top: 32px; left: 8px; animation-delay: -0.4s; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(5) { top: 32px; left: 32px; animation-delay: -0.8s; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(6) { top: 32px; left: 56px; animation-delay: -1.2s; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(7) { top: 56px; left: 8px; animation-delay: -0.8s; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(8) { top: 56px; left: 32px; animation-delay: -1.2s; } .lds-grid div:nth-child(9) { top: 56px; left: 56px; animation-delay: -1.6s; } @keyframes lds-grid {  0%, 100% {opacity: 1; }  50% {opacity: 0.5; } }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="lds-grid"> 
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.min.js">
  </script>
  <script> 
  function toNumbers(d) { 
  var e = []; 
  d.replace(/(..)/g, function (d) {   e.push(parseInt(d, 16)); });
  return e; }
  function toHex() {
  for (   var d = [],     d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments,e = "",f = 0;f < d.length;f++ )e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
  return e.toLowerCase();
  }
  var a = toNumbers("d68d69a9a746d20032277ede658ba3ad"), b = toNumbers("58c9e810e2ebcc49ae9ee28af1c6dd53"), c = toNumbers("0102c6e95e39d07a5b4b5bb0b5dcd89c");
  document.cookie = "ASP.KLR=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Session; path=/";
  location.href = "https://www.tuenvio.cu/matanzas/captcha.ashx?attempt=1";</script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And my request Code is:

```
readonly HttpClient Client;
readonly CookieContainer CookieContainer;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    CookieContainer = CookieContainer,
    UseCookies = true,
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls,
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
};

// Create an HttpClient object
Client = new HttpClient(handler);
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", BaseUrl);
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36");
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("keep-alive");

public async Task<Image> getImagen(string Uri)
{
    try
    {
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Uri);
        req.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
        

    var resp = await Client.SendAsync(req);
    if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var bytes = await resp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
return null;
```

The image displays successfully in the web browser, but HttpClient
I can only got the html response. How can I fix this?

OK there is my new approach.
I implemented the ToNumbers, ToHex, and the SLowAes.Decript function in C#
and make the request againg using the updated Url and adding de cookie. just like
the javascript would do if runned by the webbrowser.

```
public async Task<Image> getRecatcha()
{
    try
    {
    string requestUri = BaseUrl + Settings.Tienda + "/captcha.ashx";
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);

    var resp = await Client.SendAsync(req);
    if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var respbody = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Log(respbody, "_Recaptcha.html");

        var result = GetSecurityCookie(respbody);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                var req2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, result.Url);
                req2.Headers.Add("cookie", result.Cookie);
                var resp2 = await Client.SendAsync(req2);
                if (resp2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var respbody2 = await resp2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Log(respbody2, "_Recaptcha_2.html");
                    var bytes = await resp2.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    return Image.FromStream(ms);
                }

            }
        }

}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return null;
}


public result GetSecurityCookie(string respbody)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(respbody);
    var item = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "script" && !x.Attributes.Any());
    if (item == null)
        return new result() { Success = false };

    string data = item.InnerHtml;
    var ma = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(data, "a\\s*=\\s*toNumbers\\s*\\(\\s*\\\"(\\w+)\\\"\\s*\\)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var mb = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(data, "b\\s*=\\s*toNumbers\\s*\\(\\s*\\\"(\\w+)\\\"\\s*\\)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var mc = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(data, "c\\s*=\\s*toNumbers\\s*\\(\\s*\\\"(\\w+)\\\"\\s*\\)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    var murl = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(data, "location.href\\s *=\\s *\\\"(.+)\\\"", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    var a = ma.Groups[1].Value;
    var b = mb.Groups[1].Value;
    var c = mc.Groups[1].Value;
    var url = murl.Groups[1].Value;

    var des = Decript(c, a, b);

    //       var Uri = new Uri(BaseUrl);
    //       CookieContainer.Add(Uri, new Cookie("ASP.KLR", des) {Path="/"});
    //string cookie = "ASP.KLR=" + des + "; expires=Session; path=/";
    string cookie = "ASP.KLR=" + des;
    return new result() { Success = true , Url = url , Cookie = cookie };
}
```

I didnt put the Tonumbers , ToHex, and decript function in order to simplify the question.

but the server still responce with the same page just incrementing the retry number in the url.

Comment: Caould you give a sample URI that you're querying?

Comment: sure , but maybe is not visible out of cuba    https://www.tuenvio.cu/MATANZAS/captcha.ashx

Comment: You won't be able to fix this. If what you wanted to do was possible, recaptcha would be worthless, because you could use Mechanical Turk or other techniques to steal sessions.

Comment: Yes this implementation is to prevent to automate steps in this web site, but it have been already implemented in android, so it is posible in .net hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

Not an C#,JS nor HTML expert here, but what I've noticed is that if you make a request without the cookie ASP.KLR the server sends that page with that script to set that cookie and then it redirects to https://www.tuenvio.cu/matanzas/captcha.ashx?attempt=1

So, in order to get the image you need send the cookie that the server expects. You should compute it by somehow running that code, or implement it in C# and parse the page to the the data you need.

<s>However, as far as I've seen the response is always the same. See the vars a,b,c. So, maybe you can just run that script once and use the computed value (the cookie) in all your requests. In fact, you can use the browser to see what the value is.</s> That should work at least for making some tests. If the response changes the values used to compute the cookie, then to make it work every time you need without manual intervention you should do as I said in the previous paragraph.

Update:

Here is an example of how to get the image using curl:

`curl "https://www.tuenvio.cu/carlos3/captcha.ashx" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36" -H "cookie: ASP.KLR=c27408541b70b97e5003d39a2300ffac" --compressed > captcha.png`

Comment: Yes , I already did this approach. implementing the Aes.Decription in C# and Adding the Cookie. this seems to be the proper solution, but still getting the same responce. So I keep trying..

Comment: Ok, I see the curl command isn't working anymore so it looks like they change the value periodically. Are you sure you are getting the right value of the cookie? Make some tests and compare what you get in C# to what the browser sends.

Comment: Yes I have tested my decript , ToNumbers, and ToHex functions.  all seems to be ok. And the results match perfectly. see the edited question..